# Android Custom ArrayAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, row, android-arrayadapter, fragment

Hi i'm working on just making a simple list i just want an icon title and description and putting it in a fragment since it's part of a viewpager however i'm getting a nullpointerexception and i can't figure out why. My code looks like this and all my other pages are fine it's just this list i can't get to work.

```
public class Test extends Fragment{

    View view;
    Context context;
    public static ListView lView;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> leftList;

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] dayOfWeek) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, dayOfWeek);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView label=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
            label.setText(DayOfWeek[position]);
            ImageView icon=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
            if (DayOfWeek[position]=="Sunday"){
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.file);
            }else{
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            }
            TextView desc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            if (DayOfWeek[position]=="Sunday"){
                desc.setText("Description1");
            }else{
                desc.setText("desc");
            }
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftlist, null);
        LinearLayout pasteLayout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        pasteLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        context = getActivity();
        lView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        Test est = new Test();
        Test.MyCustomAdapter teS = est.new MyCustomAdapter(context, R.layout.row, R.id.rowTextView, DayOfWeek);
        leftList = teS;
        lView.setAdapter(leftList);
        return view;
    }


    String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
}
```

**The error in logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at com.testing.Test$MyCustomAdapter.getView(Test.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1445)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1220)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1131)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3160)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3160)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3160)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3160)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1873)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1304):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  278):   Force finishing activity com.testing/.MainActivity
W/ActivityManager(  278): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{408d4540 com.testing/.MainActivity}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks a ton really hoping i can get this working i think i'm really close :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `view.findViewById` but view is not instantiated yet. Instead, use the layout inflater that is passed to you in `onCreateView`, probably by passing it in to your adapter's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared View as global, but not instantiated. You can add one line to your code

```
view = convertView
```

as the first statement in getView method of adapter...

Or you can use `convertView.findViewById`